# Java web app with an external resource directory

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, war

I have a site that runs as a Java war file.  This is fine, except for referencing the sitemap.

Is it possible to configure Java/Spring/Tomcat to have a WAR file handle all of the site, and have the sitemap outside of the war?  There are a lot of links, so I have a single sitemapindex.xml file and multiple (140) sitemap.xml files.  The index file is in the root of the web app, and the sitemap files are in a folder (/sitemaps) from the root.

What I am ideally looking for is someway of saying that the /sitemaps folder is a physical folder outside of the WAR so that a different team can handle the generation of the sitemaps.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can certainly do that.  Point Apache /mywebapp/sitemaps to your physical directory or symbolic-link diretory.

Comment: Just checked and we use Tomcat, not Apache... bad me

Answer (score 1):

You could get tomcat to allow sym links

http://www.isocra.com/2008/01/following-symbolic-links-in-tomcat/

and then create one, presuming your on unix